# Chrome extension cannot load external javascript via manifest

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm working on a Chrome extension that works with the Aviary API. I need to add the Aviary Javascript to the extension. Here's what my manifest looks like:

```
"content_scripts": [ {
  "js": ["http://feather.aviary.com/js/feather.js", "jquery-1.7.2.min.js", "chosen/chosen.jquery.js", "main.js" ],
  "css": [ "assets/css/style.css" ],
}],
"permissions": [
  "http://feather.aviary.com*",
  "tabs",
  "cookies"
]
```

But it keeps throwing the error "Could not load javascript 'http://feather.aviary.com/js/feather.js' for content script." . Am I doing anything wrong? I've been searching around but haven't found the solution.

Comment: I could not find much documentation on this, but it seems like it's not possible to load js from external resource using the manifest. Can anybody confirm whether it's true?

Answer (score 2):

You should set permission example

```
 "permissions": [
    "http://*feather.aviary.com*", "webRequest",

    "tabs"
  ]
```

Comment: I've already added Aviary url in my permissions but it still doesn't work

Comment: set also in your premmision "webRequest"