# JavaScript injected through Chrome extension is not loaded

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, dom-events, inject, appendchild

I am trying to inject a JavaScript through a Chrome extension, but the script `onload` method is not called...

```
var scriptURL = 'http://'+response.scriptUrl,
    scriptTag = document.createElement('script');

scriptTag.type = 'text/javascript';
scriptTag.src = scriptURL;

function onload()
{
    alert('onload');
};
        
scriptTag.onload = onload;
$('head').append(scriptTag);
```

Any ideas why the alert isn't raised?

Comment: Do you have "webRequest" set in your manifest permissions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12275998/chrome-extension-cannot-load-external-javascript-via-manifest

Comment: i did, but it didn't help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
var scriptURL = 'http://'+response.scriptUrl,
    scriptTag = document.createElement('script');

scriptTag.type = 'text/javascript';
scriptTag.src = scriptURL;

function onload()
{
    alert('onload');
};

scriptTag.onload = onload;
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
head.appendChild(scriptTag);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! :)
Now that the event is called, i try to access one of the functions inside the script, but it doesn't recognize it... do you have an idea why?

I expect the script to be fully loaded and ready for use on the "onload" cb.